# Using custom metadata in the result of OData queries

Tags: odata

I wonder if it's possible to use custom metadata within the result of OData queries (at the entity level). I think of metadata such as scores since the query executed on an ElasticSearch database and I would like to provide these hints to the end user.

Thanks very much for your help!
Thierry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I'm not familiar with ElasticSearch. But if I understand your questions correctly, you want some information other than the raw data in the request result ?  If so, there is such things called **Instance Annotation** that may satisfy your need. An explanation from [OData spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata-json-format/v4.0/errata02/os/odata-json-format-v4.0-errata02-os-complete.html#_Toc403940652).

HTH